# How to stack individual fields in 2 column form - Foundation 4

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a two column form and i want one of the fields in the 2nd column to stack under a field in the 1st column in the mobile view. This is currently what is happening in mobile view:

First Name
Email Address
Account Number
Last Name
Contact Number

but this is what I want it to do in mobile view:

First name
Last Name
Email Address
Account Number
Contact Number

Basically I want the last name to be under the first name field in mobile view. How do I achieve this? Im not able to show you the actual page..hopefully the code will help. I want it to work like the contact form on this page: http://fixate.it/contact/ how the email address field is underneath the name field in the mobile view (small view)

Thank you :)

```
<div class="row">
        <!-- Shows -->
        <div class="large-6 small-12 columns"> 
          <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 column">
                 <form>

                      <label>First Name </label>
                        <input type="text"/>

                      <label>E-mail Address</label>
                        <input type="text"/>


                      <label>Account Number</label>
                        <input type="text"/>


            </div>
           </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="large-6 small-12 columns"> 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 column">

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                      <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text"/>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                      <label>Contact Phone #</label>
                        <div style="float:left; padding-right:11px;"><select name="phonenumcountry" id="phonenumcountry" style="width:230px;" class="chosen" autocomplete="off">
                        countries
                        </select></div>
                        <div style="float:left;"><input name="phonenum" id="phonenum" class="validate[required,funcCall[validateContactPhoneNumber]]" type="text" value=" " size="20" maxlength="16" onBlur="checkFullText4Numbers(this,event);setAsAccountNo();" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this,event)" style="vertical-align: top;" placeholder="Area Code + Phone #"></div>


                    </div>
                  </div>

            </div>

           </div>

            </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the html stacking order to reflect the stacking order going down to mobile.

To position elements you can use ,`push-6`, `.pull-6` or you can also position elements with the `.right`, `.left` class's.

here's a link to a pen showing the two methods http://cdpn.io/CKBAj

To my knowledge your better of using push and pull in the foundation column mixin if your using custom tags e.g. `@include grid-column($columns:6, $pull:6);` - align left, `@include grid-column($columns:6, $push:6);` - align right, you can also use $float:right to define the float direction. Or you can just add the classes to your html to define left and right float. personally i'm not a fan of using push, pull to align elements unless there's a reason defined by the layout and look of the page.
your should check out the foundation doc's there's loads of useful information for using foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/

A couple of notes on your code; you don't need `.small-12`, foundation is `.small-12` by default and you might be better off defining medium instead of large as in my experience form elements in the foundation grid tend to be pretty flexible.

hope this helps.